# Unity Compute Shader, Array Indexing through SV_DispatchThreadID

Tags: unity-game-engine, hlsl, directx-11, compute-shader, directcompute

I have a problem with array indexing on GPU in Compute Shader and I'm stuck with it for weeks.

I'm trying to use the x value of SV_DispatchThreadID as the index of my particle array (as it is shown in some example on the web).

It is working... But threadID variable (in main function) is always returning 0,3,6,9,12,15... not 0,1,2,3,4,...

My dispatch call on CPU side is: Dispatch(64, 1, 1);

I've tried many configuration of dispatching (32,16,1), (128,1,1),... with many configuration of numtheards (1,1,1), (32,32,1), (16,16,1)... but always the same result... threadID is NEVER well ordered.

How can I get ordered index? :(... always getting index like 0,3,6,9,...

Any suggestion?

Many Thanks.

Here is my CS kernel and my C# source:

```
#pragma kernel CSMain

float  dt;
float  time;
float  pi;

uint   maxParticles = 1024;
float  maxAge;

struct Particle 
{
    int         index;
    float3      position;
    float3      velocity; 
    float       size;
    float       age;
    float       normAge; 
    int         type;    
};

RWStructuredBuffer <Particle> particles;

[numthreads( 1, 1, 1 )]

void CSMain ( uint3 Gid : SV_GroupID, uint3 DTid : SV_DispatchThreadID, uint3 GTid : SV_GroupThreadID, uint GI : SV_GroupIndex )        
{
    uint index = DTid.x;

    if (index < maxParticles)
    {
        Particle p = particles[index];
        p.position.y = p.index; //just check if the index is correct by giving a Y position
        particles[index] = p;   
    }

}
```

C# code to create the ComputeBuffer and other stuff:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class SimpleEmitter : MonoBehaviour 
{
   struct Particle 
    {
        public int          index;
        public Vector3      position;
        public Vector3      velocity;
        public float        size;
        public float        age;
        public float        normAge;
        public int          type;
    }

    public ComputeShader computeShader;
    public Material material;
    public int maxParticles = 1000000;
    public float maxAge = 3.0f; 
    public float particleSize = 0.5f;

    private ComputeBuffer particles;
    private int particleSizeOf;

    void Start () 
    {   
        Particle p = new Particle();
        particleSizeOf = Marshal.SizeOf(p);

        Particle[] pInitBuffer = new Particle[maxParticles];

        for (int i = 0; i < maxParticles; i++) 
        {
            p = new Particle();
            p.index = i;
            p.type = 0;            
            p.age = 0;
            p.normAge = 0.1f;
            p.size = particleSize * 0.5f + Random.value * particleSize;                     
            p.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

            pInitBuffer[i] = p;
        }

        particles = new ComputeBuffer(maxParticles, particleSizeOf, ComputeBufferType.Default);
        particles.SetData(pInitBuffer);

        computeShader.SetBuffer(0, "particles", particles);
    }

    void Update() 
    {       
        computeShader.SetFloat("dt", Time.deltaTime);
        computeShader.SetFloat("time", Time.time);
        computeShader.SetFloat("pi", Mathf.PI);     
        computeShader.SetInt("maxParticles", maxParticles);                
        computeShader.SetFloat("maxAge", maxAge);

        computeShader.Dispatch(0, 64, 1, 1);            
    }

    public void OnPostRender() 
    {
        material.SetPass(0);
        material.SetFloat("maxAge", maxAge);
        material.SetBuffer("particles", particles);

        Graphics.DrawProcedural(MeshTopology.Triangles, maxParticles, 0);
    }

    void OnDisable() 
    {
        particles.Release();
    }
}
```

Here the Vertex, Geom and Pixel Shader :

```
Shader "Custom/SimpleRS" 
{
    Properties 
    {
        _ParticleTexture ("Diffuse Tex", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Ramp1Texture ("G_Ramp1", 2D) = "white" {}
    }

    SubShader 
    {
        Pass 
        {
            Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
            Blend OneMinusDstColor One
            Cull Off 
            Lighting Off 
            ZWrite Off 
            Fog { Color (0,0,0,0) }


            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma target 5.0
            #pragma vertex VSMAIN
            #pragma fragment PSMAIN
            #pragma geometry GSMAIN
            #include "UnityCG.cginc" 

            struct Particle 
            {
                int    index;
                float3 position;
                float3 velocity;
                float  size;
                float  age;
                float  normAge;
                int    type;

            };

            StructuredBuffer<Particle>  particles;

            Texture2D                   _ParticleTexture;           
            SamplerState                sampler_ParticleTexture;

            Texture2D                   _Ramp1Texture;
            SamplerState                sampler_Ramp1Texture;

            float maxAge;
            float maxRad;

            struct VS_INPUT
            {
                uint vertexid           : SV_VertexID;
            };
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            struct GS_INPUT
            {
                float4 position         : SV_POSITION;
                float size              : TEXCOORD0;
                float age               : TEXCOORD1;
                float type              : TEXCOORD2;
            };
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            struct PS_INPUT
            {
                float4 position         : SV_POSITION;
                float2 texcoords        : TEXCOORD0;
                float size              : TEXCOORD1;
                float age               : TEXCOORD2;
                float type              : TEXCOORD3;
            };
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            GS_INPUT VSMAIN( in VS_INPUT input )
            {
                GS_INPUT output;

                output.position.xyz = particles[input.vertexid].position;
                output.position.w = 1.0;                
                output.age = particles[input.vertexid].normAge;
                output.size = particles[input.vertexid].size;
                output.type = particles[input.vertexid].type;
                return output;
            }
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            [maxvertexcount(4)]
            void GSMAIN( point GS_INPUT p[1], inout TriangleStream<PS_INPUT> triStream )
            {           
                float4 pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, p[0].position);

                float halfS = p[0].size * 0.5f;
                float4 offset = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_P, float4(halfS, halfS, 0, 1));

                float4 v[4];
                v[0] = pos + float4(offset.x, offset.y, 0, 1);
                v[1] = pos + float4(offset.x, -offset.y, 0, 1);
                v[2] = pos + float4(-offset.x, offset.y, 0, 1);
                v[3] = pos + float4(-offset.x, -offset.y, 0, 1);

                PS_INPUT pIn;
                pIn.position = v[0];
                pIn.texcoords = float2(1.0f, 0.0f);

                    pIn.size = p[0].size;
                    pIn.age = p[0].age;
                    pIn.type = p[0].type;                       

                triStream.Append(pIn);

                pIn.position =  v[1];
                pIn.texcoords = float2(1.0f, 1.0f);
                triStream.Append(pIn);

                pIn.position =  v[2];
                pIn.texcoords = float2(0.0f, 0.0f);
                triStream.Append(pIn);

                pIn.position =  v[3];
                pIn.texcoords = float2(0.0f, 1.0f);
                triStream.Append(pIn);                  
            }
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            float4 PSMAIN( in PS_INPUT input ) : COLOR
            {
                float4 color = _ParticleTexture.Sample( sampler_ParticleTexture, input.texcoords );
                float4 tint = _Ramp1Texture.Sample(sampler_Ramp1Texture, float2(min(1.0, input.age),0));
                color *= tint;

                if (input.age == 0) discard;

                return color;
            }
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ENDCG
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: The fact that it's every 3 particles that doesn't seem to be correct makes me think it's more likely it's the material that's drawing them that's wrong. I'm not familiar with Unity or Graphics.DrawProcedural but it feels like the 'every 3rd one' is more down to the fact that you're using triangles to draw them.

Can I see the vertex shader used by 'material'?

Comment: If you haven't yet tried using PIX For Windows, AMD GPUPerfStudio, NVIDIA Nsight, Intel GPA or the Graphics Debugger built into Visual Studio 2012 then these are also good options. PIX For Windows has issues with Win 8. GPUPerfStudio works on both AMD and Nvidia cards for debugging purposes, nSight is NVIDIA only and Intel GPA works on all cards. Alternatively if you can provide a small executable that reproduces the problem I can probably PIX it and have a better idea of what's wrong.

Comment: I've just added the code for Vertex, Geom and Pixel shaders.

Comment: And here is a small executable ;)
http://www.cornflex.org/files/DX11CSUnity.zip

As you will see, this scene contains a set of cube, juste to compare the Y values of particles... and we can see it is like 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, ...

Comment: I'm just working through it, but the StructuredBuffer itself is fine in the debugger, the values 0 through 31 are in the position.y position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be drawing with MeshTopology.Points not Triangles.

Since the geometry shader is passed only a point, that's your topology, the GS then handles expanding this out into triangles as per your shader code.

This explains why only every 3rd particle is showing up. They're being passed to the GS in groups of 3 as per your requested topology, you're then discarding the 2nd and 3rd input transparently and the next vertex the GS sees is Vertex 3, then 6, then 9 etc.